I'm trying to find a B/W sci fi movie
I remember that two men and a woman were picked up by a space ship. They were in a room that was lined with boxes, somewhat like post office boxes. They figured out how to open them and found useful items. At that point I had to leave so I don't have anything else to go on. I've been trying to figure this out for years.

Did it involve some kind of magnet key that they had to place in a certain location on the box?

Yes, as I remember they had a piece that stuck on the box door, which opened it.

Yeah I know that movie. I just have to find out what it's called. It's been a while LOL. So fingers crossed.

Here's some more details that might ring the bell for others: a bunch of people are transported to an abandoned alien space base. There they undergo a series of tests. There's that box puzzle. They also get faced with a monster to see how they react. The girl gives it some food (spikey looking fruit things) and the pass the test.

Here's the movie I was remembering: The Terrornauts. It isn't B&W but it is old (1960). Here is the full film on YouTube. The scene with boxes lining the wall is at around the 40:08 mark.

That is indeed what I've been looking for these many years. My recollection is a bit off since it's been almost fifty years. Thanks for the help.
